# 16 Character Unique ID with MongoDB + NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, uuid

I am looking for an efficient way to create UUIDs in base 64 with a length of 16 characters. Every ID needs to be compelety random so you cant predict the other IDs.

Also I am not sure how to check if a collision happens, how I can look for them in an efficent way. I am using a mongoDB and as a server Node JS.

An Example:
I call the function to create 1.000.000 Keys and in the Database are already millions of keys saved. How can I guarantee that every key is existing only ones withouth comparing every key to the existing ones in the database?

I hope somebody can help me. Thanks :)

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried generating a random base 64 number with `crypto.js` and making the uuid index unique in mongoDB? Also, your question is unclear, do you want a better random function or a better way of checking if the uuid is already in the DB? If it's indexed it won't be checked against every other key in the db.

Answer (score 0):

As for generating such an ID, as we know Base64 encoding is approximately 1/3 larger than the original binary, we can simply generate 12 bytes of randomness, then encode it:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

function generateRandomID() {
    return new Promise((res) => {
        crypto.randomBytes(12, (err, buf) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            const enc = buf.toString('base64');
            if(enc.length !== 16) throw 'invalid';
            res(enc);
        });
    });
}

generateRandomID()
    .then((id) => console.log(id))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

I'm no MongoDB expert, but I'm quite sure it has unique indexes, so you'd just try and add a document with the same ID as a previously existing one, and it'd fail.

Comment: only if the ID has been used as objectID, otherwise you have to manually add a unique index on that filed.

Comment: Yes the UUIDs would be the objectIDs. If I would bulk.insert() those keys and get a "duplicate key error", would the rest be inserted anyway? And would I get the count or name of those duplicates ?